# An order of 52 is placed and only 50 is passed through the API into our ERP for logged in customer

Tags: api, product, bigcommerce, erp

Scenario:
Orders placed with over 50 unique products are not being passed through the API correctly and are being cut off at 50 (An order of 52 is placed and only 50 is passed through the API into our ERP). After contacting BigCommerce’s API team, we learned that this limitation is in place if the order is considered a ‘Guest’ order. This shouldn’t be the case as all our customers need to have an account with us to place an order.

Expected result: Limitation isn’t in place for logged in users.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: cannot do much without the exact API call being used, and a sample of the response. @Nathan Booker is right, it's probably being paged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you paginating the order products? The default page size for most API responses is 50, so you might just be seeing the first page only.

You can increase the page size like this:

```
GET /v2/orders/ID/products?limit=250
```

(Maximum is 250)

And if there are more than 250, you can get the next page using the `page` parameter:

```
GET /v2/orders/ID/products?limit=250&page=2
```

To understand how many products there are before paginating, there is also a `count` endpoint:

```
GET /v2/orders/ID/products/count
```

Comment: I am new to bigcommerce. Can you explain where I do your changes?

Comment: How are you connecting to the API? Are you using one of the clients, or making your own API connection?